Kendo modules latest update using @use @forward brought to problems with theme
After the Latest Kendo-modules update (v17) in node modules, kendo start using @use @forward as the latest SCSS updates make @import deprecated.
I overwrite some of the kendo-variables in my theme modules as I want to have another color scheme or variable meanings.
After the new version because of @use @forward I got errors onthe build which errors that I have multiple definitions for the same named variable (for ex, "$kendo-button-bg").
If I don't want to use @use namespaces to separate them, is there another solution to fix my error?

